# ¿Cómo obtener todos los registros duplicados en postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Como podría obtener todos los registros duplicados en base a una columna, por ejemplo tengo la tabla codigo:

```
╔════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ id ║ codigo_1 ║ codigo_2 ║
╠════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ cod_abc  ║ cod_123  ║
╠════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║  2 ║ cod_xyz  ║ cod_234  ║
╠════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║  3 ║ cod_abc  ║ cod_345  ║
╠════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║  4 ║ cod_mno  ║ cod_456  ║
╠════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║  5 ║ cod_stv  ║ cod_567  ║
╠════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║  6 ║ cod_bcd  ║ cod_678  ║
╚════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

Quiero obtener todos los registros duplicados de la columna codigo_1, por ejemplo la salida de lo que quiero sería:

```
╔════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ id ║ codigo_1 ║ codigo_2 ║
╠════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ cod_abc  ║ cod_123  ║
╠════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║  3 ║ cod_abc  ║ cod_345  ║
╚════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
select * from codigo ou
where (select count(*) from codigo inr
where inr.codigo_1 = ou.codigo_1) > 1
```

Pero eso consulta solo me retorna un registro duplicado de cada duplicado.

**¿Qué consulta podría realizar para lograr lo que deseo?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar el comando `OVER`:

```
SELECT id, codigo_1, codigo_2
FROM (  SELECT  *, 
                COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY codigo_1) N
        FROM codigo) as A
WHERE N > 1
```

[**Acá**](http://rextester.com/DJO33863) puedes encontrar una demo con este código.

Los resultados son:

```
╔════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ id ║ codigo_1 ║ codigo_2 ║
╠════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ cod_abc  ║ cod_123  ║
║  3 ║ cod_abc  ║ cod_345  ║
╚════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: Gracias @Lamak, me sirvió tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Se trata de:

- Enfrentar las columnas de la tabla contra sí mismas
- Mostrar las columnas pkey, y otra información relevante
- Funciona rápido

---

```
Select tb1.pkey,tb1.column2,tb1.column3,tb2.pkey,tb2.column2,tb2.column3
  From tabla tb1, tabla tb2
  Where tb1.column2 = tb2.column2
  And   tb1.pkey <> tb2.pkey ;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT primary_key, columna2, .._
FROM tabla
GROUP BY primary_key, columna2,..
HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: esto no es una respuesta a la pregunta  podrias agregar una descripcion y adaptar el query a las tablas  y campos mencionados?